# krajee bootstrap file input disable/remove upload icon preview thumbnail

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I need to disable upload button. It's possible?

[image]

Comment: give id="f"  to your button $('#f').attr('disabled','disabled'); that's it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to @lyhoshva,

```
    $("#attachments").fileinput({
        'showUpload': false
    });
```

[Krajee Documentation, see block 2a](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input#usage)

Comment: This hide the Upload button from control bar not in the preview thumbnail. This "issue" give you an example of how you can handle this: https://github.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput/issues/907. Sorry for my english

Answer (score 17):

here may be this can help you,

```
fileActionSettings: {
                        showRemove: false,
                        showUpload: false,
                        showZoom: true,
                        showDrag: false,},
```

Comment: guys this the right answer! cheers bro OP please accept this answer to close this question

Answer (score 1):

Set

```
'pluginOptions' => [
    'showRemove' => false,
]
```

or, if you use js

```
"pluginOptions" : {
    "showRemove" : false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out below code

showClose: false,
showCaption: false,
showBrowse: false,
showUpload:false,
showUploadedThumbs: false,
showPreview: true,

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it's not the ideal solution but it worked for me.
Add this style

```
.kv-file-upload {
   display:none;
}
```

and button is gone